# Repeat the column label on row group line in gt

Tags: r, gt

I am building a long table using gt, and I would like to know if there is a way to repeat the column labels on row group line.

[image: Structure of a gt table]

On the image of gt table, repeat the "COLUMN LABEL" on the hatched parts of "ROW GROUP LABEL" line.

Thanks for your response